# WordPress Media manager select file button, how to prevent hiding?

Tags: uploads, media-modal

In a customized mediamanager (base versione 3.5) I would like to keep displayed the "select file" button even when some files are already uploaded in the album. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Please read [ask] and file an [edit] for your question and explain your problem with a bit more detail. Also show your research.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for format of my code. Please any one help me to edit this code format.

" Use below code in function file in your theme. After that it will display an option in Admin> appearance>Homepage below image 1 . From there you can upload image."

```
function register_my_logo(){ register_setting('logo_options_group','logo_options_group'); }add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_logo' ); 
function add_logo_page_to_settings() {


add_theme_page('Theme Logo',
'Homepage below image 1 ->',
'manage_options',
'edit_logo',
'logo_edit_page'); }
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_logo_page_to_settings');
function logo_edit_page() {?>

 <div class="section panel">
  <h1>Custom homepage images and url change</h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields('logo_options_group'); // this will come later
    do_settings_sections('logo_options_group'); // and this too...
    ?> 
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
    </p>
  </form>
 <?php  }function add_logo_options_to_page(){add_settings_section(
'custom_logo',
'Customize the site homepage image:',
'custom_logo_fields',
'logo_options_group' );
$args=array(); // pass arguments to add_settings_array to use in fields
add_settings_field( 'logo_url', "image", 'logo_upload_url' , 'logo_options_group', 'custom_logo', $args );
add_settings_field('title','Title','logo_upload_url','logo_options_group','logo_options_group',$args);

add_settings_field(
          'cus_url', //id
          'Custom URL', //title
          'logo_upload_url', //callback
          'logo_options_group', //page
          'logo_options_group', //section
          $args
      );}
add_action('admin_init','add_logo_options_to_page');  
function logo_upload_url($args){$options=get_option('logo_options_group') ;?>

<br><label for="upload_image"><input id="url" type="text" size="36" value="<?php echo $options['url']; ?>" name="logo_options_group[url]" /><input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /><br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#upload_logo_button').click(function() {
  formfield = jQuery('#url').attr('name');
  tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
  return false;});
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
jQuery('#url').val(imgurl);
tb_remove(); }});</script>


<?php if($options['url']){
echo "<br>This is your current logo: <br><img src='". $options['url'] ."' style='padding:20px;' />";
echo "<br>To use it in a theme copy this: <blockquote>". htmlspecialchars("<?php do_shortcode('[sitelogo]'); ?>") ."</blockquote><br> To use it in a post or page copy this code:<blockquote>[sitelogo]</blockquote>";  } ?>


<br>This is your current Title: <br><input type="text" id="title" name="logo_options_group[title]" value="<?php echo $options['title']; ?>" /> <br>This is your current URL: <br><input type="text" id="cus_url" name="logo_options_group[cus_url]" value="<?php echo $options['cus_url']; ?>" />

<?php}function custom_logo_fields(){**// you can add stuff here if you like...**}

function my_admin_scripts() {wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');}

function my_admin_styles() { wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); }
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'edit_logo') {add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts'); add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_styles'); }
function get_site_logo(){$option=get_option("logo_options_group"); if($option['url']){echo "<img src='". $option['url'] ."' />";} else {echo "Sorry, No logo selected";}} add_shortcode('sitelogo', 'get_site_logo');
```

```
 Then to display that image in your template use this code.
```

```
<?php $option=get_option('logo_options_group') ; ?>
<div><a href="<?php echo $option['cus_url']; ?>"><?php do_shortcode('[sitelogo]'); ?><?php echo $option['title']; ?></a></div>
```